# Como crear un json apartir de un array de valores y añadirle un key

Tags: javascript, angularjs, json

Tengo un array en forma de json de la siguiente manera

```
[   "Sin clasificar",
    "Pedimento Aduanal",
    "Facturas de Gastos (A cuenta de Terceros)",
    "COVE",
    "Facturas de Mercancías (Compra de Mercancias)",
    "Guía aérea, conocimiento de embarque o carta de porte"
]
```

y me gustaria que quedara de la siguiente forma y saber si hay algun problema con que duplique los keys ? es que quiero repetir los values con el ng-repear del angular y cuando es un array de cadenas de texto me repite muchas veces el dato

```
[{
    "tipodescrip": "Sin clasificar",
    "tipodescrip": "Pedimento Aduanal",
    "tipodescrip": "Facturas de Gastos (A cuenta de Terceros)",
    "tipodescrip": "COVE",
    "tipodescrip": "Facturas de Mercancías (Compra de Mercancias)",
    "tipodescrip": "Guía aérea, conocimiento de embarque o carta de porte"
  }]
```

alguna sugerencia?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Te recomendaria hacer un Map, y adicionarle una key generica.

```
//Este seria tu array de strings 

   var _arrayOriginal = [   "Sin clasificar",
        "Pedimento Aduanal",
        "Facturas de Gastos (A cuenta de Terceros)",
        "COVE",
        "Facturas de Mercancías (Compra de Mercancias)",
        "Guía aérea, conocimiento de embarque o carta de porte"
    ]
   var _arrayFinal = new Array();
   _arrayOriginal.map((obj,index) => {
   _arrayFinal.push({
              tipodescrip:obj,
              key:index
             });
   });

   //y finalmente objenemos el json

   var myJsonString = JSON.stringify(_arrayFinal);
```

Nos daría este resultado

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Excelente , funciono muy bien! eres un crack!

saludos.

Answer (score 1):

Si todos van a tener el mismo key, no te convendria meterlos dentro de un objeto de esta manera?

```js
var arr = [   
    "Sin clasificar",
    "Pedimento Aduanal",
    "Facturas de Gastos (A cuenta de Terceros)",
    "COVE",
    "Facturas de Mercancías (Compra de Mercancias)",
    "Guía aérea, conocimiento de embarque o carta de porte"
]
var obj = {
    tipodescrip : arr
}

console.log(obj)
```

Comment: Te agradezco ! funciono bien tambien!

Answer (score 1):

Si lo que quieres es mostrar los valores en un `ng-repeat`, con tu array es suficiente.

Además, ng-repeat no debería duplicarte errores.

Fijate en este ejemplo para que corrobores como se usa:

```
<body ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">

<h1 ng-repeat="x in records">{{x}}</h1>

<script>
var app = angular.module("myApp", []);
app.controller("myCtrl", function($scope) {
    $scope.records = [
        "Sin clasificar",
        "Pedimento Aduanal",
        "Facturas de Gastos (A cuenta de Terceros)",
        "COVE",
        "Facturas de Mercancías (Compra de Mercancias)",
        "Guía aérea, conocimiento de embarque o carta de porte"
    ]
});
</script>

</body>
```

(Sacado de [w3school](https://www.w3schools.com/angular/ng_ng-repeat.asp))

Para que lo veas trabajando podés verlo en [este plunker](https://next.plnkr.co/edit/FM86W8QpxMG6voVp)

Comment: Debes buscar la documentación de angularjs

Comment: Hay alguna falta en el código? O qué es en especifico lo que me pides que busque en la codumentacion ?

Comment: Muchas Gracias!